# How to poll through a memory stream while accessing that memory stream?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, stream, memorystream

I am trying to build an app that streams music to another app. The receiver side reads bytes, then saves them into a temp file, and plays that temp file. But between parts of the song, there is a small delay (when one part starts, and the next one is getting saved). I already got the player in a background task. So I would like to try to write the stream into the file while the player is reading the said file. All of this is being done over a working Bluetooth connection.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
{
    Java.IO.File temp = Java.IO.File.CreateTempFile("temp", "mp3");
    Java.IO.FileInputStream fis = new Java.IO.FileInputStream(temp);
    temp.DeleteOnExit();

    MediaPlayer player;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[10000];
            Java.IO.FileOutputStream fos = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(temp);

            mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
            fos.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);

            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.SetDataSource(fis.FD);
            player.Prepare();
            player.Start();
            while (true)
            {
               if (!player.IsPlaying)
               {
                  player.Release();
                  break;
               }
            }
         }
         catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
         {
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input stream was disconnected", ex);
         }
     } 
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

So the mmInStream is a System.IO.Stream. The second while loop checks if a chunk has been played, to release the resources. This is done in Xamarin.Forms

---

If I define it before the loop, I get this exception:

```
Java.IO.File temp = Java.IO.File.CreateTempFile("temp", "mp3");
Java.IO.FileInputStream fis = new Java.IO.FileInputStream(temp);
temp.DeleteOnExit();

MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[10000];
        Java.IO.FileOutputStream fos = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(temp);
        mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
        fos.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
        player.SetDataSource(fis.FD);
        player.Prepare();
        player.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            if (!player.IsPlaying)
            {
                player.Stop();
                player.Reset();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input stream was disconnected", ex);
    }
}
```

Placed the MediaPlayer outside, with the if santance to check and stop then reset and it works, but still get the short pause.

Comment: Literally stopped to upvote this. Good luck getting your answer MTS!

Comment: Why are you creating a new MediaPlayer and Sopping/Starting the Player which take a lot of time?

Comment: @jdweng I think that's what he's trying to figure out. He'd like to be able to simultaneously load data to his media player while playing the currently buffered data. Now, it skips with every iteration, loop.

Comment: The writing is very quick since the MediaPlayer is buffering the data.  No need to have all the extra code.

Comment: One simple design idea would be to store the data, not in a temporary "file," but in temporary *"files"* that are, say, consecutively numbered.  The writer process creates a new file each time ... locking the file to ensure that the reader cannot open it prematurely.  Meanwhile, the reader locks a file, plays it, discards it, and then attempts to lock, play, and discard the next one.  (You'll separately need to decide what it means if the reader finds no file there.  Various race-condition possibilities do exist.)

Comment: @jdweng If I create it only once outside of the loop, it will only play once

Comment: You must be getting an underflow.  Are you getting an exception?  The MediaPlayer must be defined and start before the first while loop while(true). Or start only the first time inside the loop.

Comment: @jdweng If I define it before the while loop, I am getting an exception, Unable to create MediaPlayer (will post it above)

Comment: You are getting the error because you are trying to open two MediaPlayers.  You need to move : player = new MediaPlayer(); as well as other code that only needs to be run once.

Comment: I did delete the one and start only one(as above)

Comment: I tried to stream into multiple files aswell, but that to has a short stop

Comment: Here's a thought if you haven't considered it yet: I know that MP3s have "padding" on them so that if you stop an MP3 and start another one, there is a slight delay unlike WAV files which can play continuously (some kind of side effect of FFT transforms?). Is it possible that's what you're seeing?

Comment: @Slothario Maybe it is that, is it possible to remove that padding?

Comment: @MTS I'm not sure, but unless there's some workaround for it it seems like the best course of action might be to scrap the file storage and see how others address buffering -- it's a solved problem. There might be out-of-the-box solutions, too.